# Can styled components handle computations like SCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

With SCSS, I can create CSS magic like so:

```
@for $i from 1 through $total-items {
  li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: .25s * $i;
  }
}
```

I'm now working on a React App that uses styled components. Does styled components allow for the above somehow?

Comment: You can use javascript to do the same thing cutting out the middle man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut out the middleman and do the calculation during the render or you can pass an index to something that returns an object that will generate your style.

```
totalItems.map((item, index) => {
   <li style={animationDelay: `${.25 * index}s`}>{item.name}</li>
})
```

otherwise you can create a style and pass in the index to create the style object

```
const style = (index) => {
  return {
    animationDelay: `${.25 * index}s`
  }
}
```

But if you're looking for the styled component way
pass your component here with an attr of `index={the index of the item}`

```
const StyledLink = styled(component here)`
    animationDelay: ${props => props.index};
`;
```